# Loading pandas dataframe from a URL

Tags: pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I tried to load a data frame from a URL

```py
url = 'https://ncdc.herokuapp.com/ncdc-covid-data/epicurve-by-date?state=akwa%20ibom'

df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

so instead of a data frame with several rows, I just got a lump of columns instead. any help will be appreciated.

[image: sample result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The URL contains `JSON`, not a `CSV`, data.
- The information of interest is in the `'data'` key
- Read the URL with [`pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)
- Read the `'data'` column with [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://ncdc.herokuapp.com/ncdc-covid-data/epicurve-by-date?state=akwa%20ibom'

data = pd.json_normalize(pd.read_json(url)['data'])

# display(data.head())
          _id  total_confirmed_cases  total_discharged  total_deaths  total_active_cases  new_confirmed_cases  new_discharged  new_deaths
0  2020-06-29                     86                54             2                  30                  0.0             0.0         0.0
1  2020-06-28                     86                54             2                  30                  3.0            11.0         0.0
2  2020-06-27                     83                43             2                  38                  0.0             0.0         0.0
3  2020-06-26                     83                43             2                  38                  0.0             0.0         0.0
4  2020-06-25                     83                43             2                  38                  0.0             0.0         0.0
```